# CSS element shows on the webpage

Tags: html, css

I have simple responsive table , it works fine, but on the webpage, CSS code show

```
<style>
  table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
  }

  th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }

  tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Slovenia</td> </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Online `CSS border collapse` shown on the webpage

is there any reason? Thanks Mahmoud

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code, and when I put it into a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/brettgaynor/tckdzg9h/2/) I don't see any CSS style literally printed on the page. Can you provide a bit more info or clarify what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `<style>` is inside the `<head>` tag. The other html code belongs into the body. If you put style inside html, it's getting printed out.

Comment: No problem, I am happy to help! Good luck @Mahmoud

Answer (score 0):

My only assumption is that you are not actually reading the file correctly. Is it saved as a .html file? even with the style tags in the body this should work.